# Pidgin's Google Talk plugin dropping messages

Tags: pidgin, google-talk, adium

Until a few days ago, I used Pidgin's Google Talk plugin to talk to a few people (who are using adium, so still libpurple afaik) and it all worked fine, even though as far as I know gtalk has been moribund for almost a decade. Starting recently, however, it began taking forever to sign in, and messages have been being dropped in both directions.

If I sign in via Google *Chat*, I can send and receive messages faithfully. But since my interlocutors aren’t signed in directly to chat, but only to talk, I don't see (in Pidgin) whether they’re actually active, or idle, or what. So, although this does work, it’s a worse experience.

Is this a known issue that others have experienced? Is Google Talk support flaky now?

Comment: We've been tracking this in our issue tracker at https://issues.imfreedom.org/issue/PIDGIN-17564

Answer (score 1):

FYI - There is a new plugin for Pidgin, Google talk, which put me back in business.  I tried a few other programs such as Discord, Trillion, facebook chat etc but I didn't like the screen size.  Luckily I got Pidgin to work again with GoogleChat instead of XMPP since that been discontinued.

Answer (score -1):

gmail/google no longer supports pidgin. So you're better getting off of google and move to discord, utox/qtox or other alts. Google is a lost cause by now. Corrupt they want to know everything you do 24/7 with 0 privacy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).